# image enlarge on hover with content inside div box attached to image

Tags: jquery, image, hover, mouseover, image-enlarge

I was wondering if someone can guide me towards building a script where I can enlarge the image by hovering over with my mouse, but the image isn't only going to be enlarged, a div around the image will also be attached to it that appears when you hover

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way. Put the code somewhere in your resizables.js file.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2012, Val Kotlarov Hoffman.
 * Licensed under the GPL Version 2 license.
 * You may copy freely and distribute as long as this comment remains.
 **/

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    init_resizeables();
});

function init_resizeables() {

    $('img').hover(
        function() { 
            $(this).stop().animate({
                'width':'444px'
            },{
                duration:234
            }).css({
                'z-index':'999', 
                'position':'absolute'
            });
        },
        function() { 
            $(this).stop().animate({
                'width':'254px'
            },{
                duration:345
            }).css({
                'z-index':'1'
            });
        });
}
```

The first with is the width of the zoomed image. The second width is image's normal size. Simply include this in your html file and you're done. Change the *img* selector to whatever you need. 
Enjoy.