# image enlarge on hover and clearQueue

Tags: jquery, effects

i came across the following question which is pretty much what i need except one thing.

[image enlarge on hover with content inside div box attached to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632539/image-enlarge-on-hover-with-content-inside-div-box-attached-to-image)

best answer example:
http://demo.superdit.com/jquery/zoom_hover/

when i'm on mouseover and then mouseout  a couple of times very fast, the animation continues to play a couple of times way after the mouse is out.

how can the animation play only once after mouseout without jagged movement ?

thanks.

Comment: Show us the relevant code. But I'm pretty sure it will be [yet another question about `.stop()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11495892/417685)

Comment: the code is the example: http://demo.superdit.com/jquery/zoom_hover/

Comment: I hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q7TX2/2/) help you. Changes to the animate where necessary to compel to the `.stop()` event. Depending of your current page's styles it won't affect you [too much]

Comment: Let me put that as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/q7TX2/4/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cont_left = $("#container").position().left;
  $("a img").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var left = $this.position().left, top = $this.position().top;
    $(this).hover(function() {
      // hover in
      $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 1);
      $(this).stop().animate({
        height: "250",
        width: "250",
        left: left - 50,
        top: top - 50
      }, "fast");
    }, function() {
      // hover out
      $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 0);
      $(this).stop().animate({
        height: "150",
        width: "150",
        left: left,
        top: top
      }, "fast");
    });
  });

  $(".img").each(function(index) {
    var left = (index * 160) + cont_left;
    $(this).css("left", left + "px");
  });
});​
```

Changes made:

- Added [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).
- Fixed positioning of the animation to make it compel with `.stop()` (make it stoppable.)